# phonegap/jquerymobile IOS external link and a back button

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am building an iphone app with phonegap and jquery mobile. In the app, there is a button which opens a external website. If the website is already opened there isn't any back to the app button. How can I implement that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that from an external site because you don't have access to the cordova.js with it's functions any more.

What you should do instead is open the external URL in a child browser https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ChildBrowser

You could also open the external URL in Safari rather than in the app UIWebView.